# Mirroring in a plane using a matrix transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The matrix below represents a mirroring about a plane. I'm curious how one would find out which plane? I would think it's a mirroring about $x=y$  including a translation. But the -1 and 1 in the last column confuse me so I'm not quite sure about my answer.

\begin{bmatrix}
 0&  1& 0& -1& \\ 
 1&  0& 0&  1& \\ 
 0&  0& 1&  0& \\ 
 0&  0& 0&  1& 
\end{bmatrix}

Is there a shorthand trick to figure out which plane is being mirrored about?

Comment: The matrix you give doesn't quite make sense as a "mirroring": a reflection transformation should be from the same space as it is into, i.e. a transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and not $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ when $n \neq m$. However, your matrix is $4 \times 3$, which poses a problem.

Comment: I apparently missed a column.. very stupid. But I already figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
The first 2 columns are switched so $x=y$ and $y=x$ now. The last column states what either $x$ or $y$ is equal to.

For the first row, $y$ is in the second column so $y = 1$ and for the second row in the first column $x = -1$.

So the line that it's being mirrored about is $x-y+1$ = 0. Because if I set $y=0$ then $x=-1$ and if I set $x=0$ then $y=1$ just like the equation states.